# Updating IP in FreeDNS eg. in 5 seconds instead of an hour via script

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, subdomain, shell

Like the title says. At freedns.afraid.org website interface I can set the TTL if I'm premium. But how can I set it to 5s instead of the default 1h using/extending this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#FreeDNS updater script

UPDATEURL="http://freedns.afraid.org/dynamic/update.php?_YOURAPIKEYHERE_"
DOMAIN="_YOURDOMAINHERE_"

registered=$(nslookup $DOMAIN|tail -n2|grep A|sed s/[^0-9.]//g)

  current=$(wget -q -O - http://checkip.dyndns.org|sed s/[^0-9.]//g)
       [ "$current" != "$registered" ] && {                           
          wget -q -O /dev/null $UPDATEURL 
          echo "DNS updated on:"; date
  }
```

UPDATE: using a direct link, it takes ~5 min for the update to take effect. The update itself does not even take a 1s.

Comment: There is no timer in that script.  You need to adjust the way the script is being called.

Comment: I would call it at every startup.

Comment: In that case it is not running every hour.

Comment: No but the update takes an hour. If I execute this script (or change the IP manually at the website) the IP mapped to the subdomain changes only 1 hour later.

Comment: Oh, that is asking a different question than I understood it.  In that case, it is unlikely you would be able to modify the script to produce the desired result; you would need to look at the API for the specific DDNS service provider.  However, if you need 5 second granularity your business should probably invest in a static IP with a business-grade ISP.

Comment: I've found a way to do it with a direct link like this: https://freedns.afraid.org/dynamic/update.php?_SOMELONGHASH_ Now it takes only 5 minutes.